# How to make these two "col" stack in a different order on mobile? Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have these col-md-8 and col-md-4 they are correctly displayed on desktop, but on mobile they stack in the wrong order. How do I attach bootstrap classes in order to make them stack the other way.

```
<footer class="container-fluid footerInfo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 f1">
            <h6>Advocacy Inc.</h6>
            <div class="contactWidget1">
                <p><a href="tel:1(505) 266-3166">t. +1(505)266-3166</a></p>
                <p><a href="tel:1(505)254-2559">f. +1(505)254-2559</a></p><br><br>
                <p><a href="mailto:kids@nmadvocacy.org"><i class="mailIcon fa fa-envelope-o"> kids@nmadvocacy.org</i></a></p>

            </div>
            <div class="contactWidget2">
                <p>6301 Fourth NW Suite 3<br>Albuquerque NM 87107</p>
                <p><a href="https://goo.gl/maps/yymj6bd7mnC2">View on a map.</a></p><br>
                <p class="executive">Executive Director: Gini Silva</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="f3">
                <img  class="logo2" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/assets/wlogo.png">
                <li><p>&copy;-Advocacy Inc. 2018</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 headerAfil">
            <div class="footerAfil">
                <h6>We are proudly supported by:</h6>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">New Mexico Courts.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">State Bar of New Mexico.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">United Way of Central New Mexico.</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footerAfil2">
                <a href="http://www.civicvalues.org/"><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/assets/associations/ccv.png"></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="f2">
                <li><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-map-pin"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

The bootstrap documentation explains all of this.  I'm not sure if you are using Bootstrap 3 or 4 though.

Bootstrap 3 Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering

Bootstrap 4 Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#reordering

Answer (score 1):

Add `order-1` to the classes based on the order you want to show up. Lower = first.

```
<div class="col-md-8 f1 order-1"> // First
<div class="col-md-4 f1 order-2"> // Last
```

Comment: this does not work, I need it to be on mobile, thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add classes to specify the order on desktop and mobile `<div class="col-md-8 f1 order-2 order-md-1">` and `<div class="col-md-4 headerAfil order-1 order-md-2">`.